# horizontal scroll div rendering on some mobile browsers (mainly android 2.2)

Tags: android, css, mobile, web

I have a div as such :

```
    #imgspace {
z-index:1;  
position: absolute;
top: 56px;
bottom:10px;
background-color:#ffffff;
overflow:auto;
left:15px;
right:5px;
white-space: nowrap;
display:block;}
```

and inside it I have images, floating left, as blocks.

Works great on any computer browser as a long horizontal scroll, and even on most iphones and ipads.

For some reasons their are certain phones which refuse to scroll to the right, the page is locked where it renders.

I did some research and it's possibly and issue with white-space: nowrap? Altho I could also see it being an issue with the div's absolute positioning. I really don't know. Help!?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've searched long and far, and have not come up with a solution except using a script such as jquery mobile or iscroll-4

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

If anyone knows of a simpler way, let me know! I don't want to have to convert my whole site over to some script just because older mobile OS's won't support horizontal scroll with absolute div's.

Thanks for looking!